# Simple For loop object inquiry

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

Here is the question updated and more infor on what Im trying to do:

```
Private Sub HistogramYTD(ByVal DP1 As String, ByVal DP2 As String)

    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT COUNT(ROUTE_SECONDS) AS RESULT1 FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE YEAR_TIME = '" & cbYear.Text & "' AND APE_AREA_OBJID = '" & lblAreaOBJID.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = '" & cbEmployeeName.Text & "' AND ROUTE_SECONDS >= " & DP1 & " AND ROUTE_SECONDS < " & DP2 & " AND ACTIVE = 1"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionStr)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        ' Call Read before accessing data. 
        While reader.Read()
            RESULT1 = reader("RESULT1")
        End While

        ' Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub GetHistogram()


    Dim min As Integer = 0
    Dim max As Integer = lblMaxScan.Text
    Dim range As Integer = max / 20

    Dim HistResult1, HistResult2, HistResult3, HistResult4, HistResult5, _
        HistResult6, HistResult7, HistResult8, HistResult9, HistResult10, _
        HistResult11, HistResult12, HistResult13, HistResult14, HistResult15, _
        HistResult16, HistResult17, HistResult18, HistResult19, HistResult20 _
        As Integer

    If lblShowYTDWeekly2.Text = "YTD" Then

        CountRoute()

        HistogramYTD(min, min + (range * 1))
        HistResult1 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 1) + 1, min + (range * 2))
        HistResult2 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 2) + 1, min + (range * 3))
        HistResult3 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 3) + 1, min + (range * 4))
        HistResult4 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 4) + 1, min + (range * 5))
        HistResult5 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 5) + 1, min + (range * 6))
        HistResult6 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 6) + 1, min + (range * 7))
        HistResult7 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 7) + 1, min + (range * 8))
        HistResult8 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 8) + 1, min + (range * 9))
        HistResult9 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 9) + 1, min + (range * 10))
        HistResult10 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 10) + 1, min + (range * 11))
        HistResult11 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 11) + 1, min + (range * 12))
        HistResult12 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 12) + 1, min + (range * 13))
        HistResult13 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 13) + 1, min + (range * 14))
        HistResult14 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 14) + 1, min + (range * 15))
        HistResult15 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 15) + 1, min + (range * 16))
        HistResult16 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 16) + 1, min + (range * 17))
        HistResult17 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 17) + 1, min + (range * 18))
        HistResult18 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 18) + 1, min + (range * 19))
        HistResult19 = RESULT1

        HistogramYTD(min + (range * 19) + 1, min + (range * 20))
        HistResult20 = RESULT1

    End If
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'TO CLEAR CHART AND RELOAD IT
    Chart3.Titles.Clear()
    Chart3.Series.Clear()
    Chart3.ChartAreas.Clear()
    Chart3.ChartAreas.Add("AREA")
    Chart3.Series.Add("Histogram")
    Chart3.Titles.Add("ROUTE HISTOGRAM")

    With Chart3.Titles(0)
        .Font = New Font("TAHOMA", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
    End With

    With Chart3.ChartAreas(0)
        '.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.Title = "ROUTE TIME"
        .AxisY.Title = "FREQUENCY"
        .AxisX.Minimum = 0
        .AxisX.Maximum = 21
        .AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.LabelsAngleStep30
        .AxisY.Minimum = 0
        .AxisX.Interval = 1
        .AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45
    End With

    With Chart3.Series(0)
        .Font = New Font(Me.Font.Name, 7, FontStyle.Regular)
        .SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = False
        .Label = "#VAL{P}"
        .IsValueShownAsLabel = True
        .Name = "WeeklyEfficiency"
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
        .LabelToolTip = Enabled
        .ToolTip = "FROM #VALX MINUTES." & vbNewLine & "#VAL ROUTE(S) FOR THIS RANGE."
        .BorderColor = Color.Black
        .LabelForeColor = Color.Transparent
        Dim area As String = cbArea.Text
        Select Case area
            Case "BC_PICKUP"
                .Color = Color.Blue
            Case "BC_DELIVERY"
                .Color = Color.Blue
            Case "RAW"
                .Color = Color.LimeGreen
            Case "RTV"
                .Color = Color.Yellow
            Case Else
                .Color = Color.Black
        End Select

        'LOAD DATA POINTS

        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 1), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult1)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 1) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 2), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult2)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 2) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 3), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult3)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 3) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 4), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult4)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 4) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 5), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult5)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 5) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 6), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult6)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 6) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 7), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult7)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 7) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 8), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult8)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 8) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 9), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult9)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 9) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 10), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult10)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 10) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 11), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult11)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 11) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 12), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult12)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 12) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 13), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult13)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 13) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 14), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult14)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 14) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 15), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult15)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 15) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 16), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult16)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 16) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 17), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult17)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 17) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 18), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult18)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 18) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 19), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult19)
        .Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 19) + 1, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * 20), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult20)
    End With
End Sub
```

How do i use arrays where im using similar syntaxes? or is it loops?

Comment: Really unclear. What are `HistResultXX, RESULT1 and HistogramYTD`?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve Jo?

Comment: HistResultXX is a variable stored as an integer. Result1 is an SQL query result and HistYTD is part of my SQL query string. "Private Sub HistogramYTD(ByVal DP1 As String, ByVal DP2 As String)" I just need to know how to incorporate the HistResultXX in a for loop.

Comment: we need to know what HistogramYTD does

Comment: Don't use multiple numbered variables. Use an array, list, or other collection such as hashset, dictionary etc depending on your needs. I'd probably recommend a dictionary of whatever type `min + (range * i) + 1, min + (range * (1 + i))` is by whatever type `RESULT1` is.

Comment: Are min and range variables?

Comment: Webdad3, i added what HistogramYTD does.

Comment: yes, min and range are variables

Comment: @Joseph.Scott.Garza check my answer and correct your code depending on it. Also refactor your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is array [vb.net array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-vbnet)

```
Dim HistResult(19) as Integer

For i As Integer = 0 To  HistResult.GetUpperBound(0) ' HistResult.Length-1

  HistogramYTD(min + (range * i) + 1, min + (range * (1 + i)))

  HistResult(i) = RESULT1

Next

    'plotting inside loop will be the same
    'For i As Integer = 0 To  HistResult.GetUpperBound(0) 
    ' Points.AddXY(Format(DateAdd("s", min, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss") & " - " & 'Format(DateAdd("s", min + (range * i), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss"), HistResult(i))
    ' Next
```

Plus instead of using global `RESULT1` . (I assume you are retrieving from sqldatabase an integer and store it to `RESULT1`). You should use `functions` and return result.So it will be

```
HistResult(i) =HistogramYTD(min + (range * i) + 1, min + (range * (1 + i)))
```

Coming on your sql query function.

1. instead of ExecuteQuery better use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. instead of concantenating strings to make command use
   **parameterized sql query**
3. make it `function` and parameters `integer` instead of `string`

Comment: Question. Aside from HistogramYTD, I also have HistogramWKLY. How can I interchange those two names with an if statement? I tried something like Histogram + (variable goes here) but its wrong. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/if-vbnet  But I recommend you book instead of tutorials.search vb.net books on google. And learn programming by book.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically create a variable in that way and trying to assign a value, instead you need to use a dictionary or a list depending on how do you plan to access the values stored in the collection object

For example, using a Dictionary....

```
Dim HistResult As New Dictionary(Of String, Single)

For i As Integer = 1 To 19
   HistogramYTD(min + (range * i) + 1, min + (range * (1 + i)))
   HistResult.Add(String.Format("HistResult{0}", i) , RESULT1)
Next
```

Now you have a dictionary where every key is named as your variables "HistResultXX" and you can retrieve the proper value using a syntax like this

```
Dim result = HistResult("HistResult19")
```

I have assumed that your variable `RESULT1` is of type Single, but if this is not the case then change the Dictionary declaration to the proper datatype